# In racket how do i combine strings in a list to create one sentence

Tags: list, racket

Essentially I want to combine string values in a list.
For example I want
(Join(list "cat" "is" "hungry")) to execute ("cat is hungry")

(define(join l) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Racket there's a procedure just for that, it's called [`string-join`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-join%29%29):

```
(string-join '("cat" "is" "hungry"))
=> "cat is hungry"
```

Here's another alternative, using [`string-append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-append%29%29). It's less efficient, but avoids having to code an explicit recursion:

```
(define (join lst)
  (foldl (lambda (s acc) (string-append acc " " s))
         (first lst)
         (rest  lst)))

(join '("cat" "is" "hungry"))
=> "cat is hungry"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string-append*`

See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-append*#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-append%2A%29%29